# Proof of entity (5.24) of Concrete mathematics - Page 169?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I've tried everything but can't quite figure out how to prove this entity using non-induction approach. Anyone have any idea on this entity?

$${\sum_{k}}\binom{l}{m + k}\binom{s + k}{n}(-1)^{k} = (-1)^{l + m}\binom{s - m}{n - l}, l \geq 0; n, m \in Z$$.

Concrete mathematics authors quote:

> The next one, (5.24), is a bit more dicult. We can reduce it to
> Vandermonde's convolution by a sequence of transformations.

Vandermonde's convolution: $${\sum_{k}}\binom{r}{m + k}\binom{s}{n - k} = \binom{r + s}{n + m}$$.

I found this link:  [Seemingly wrong approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575048/problem-with-two-binomial-identities-from-concrete-mathematics-book). They applied pascal's rule for $\binom{s + k}{n}$ but $s$ is in fact real !?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes! Thanks :D

Comment: For future visitors, it's fine to apply pascal's rule because of the polynomial argument and the fact that we can consider all $s$ satisfying $s \geq max(-m, 0)$